# What is the shortcut to delete entire row from table in Word 2007?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-word-2007

I want to increase my efficiency, instead of right-click -> "delete cells"-> "delete entire row" , how can i do it quickly?

i want to select a row, then press shortcut and it will delete entire row from table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### I want to select a row, then press shortcut and it will delete entire row from table

- Select the row and press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to delete the row.
- Select the row and press <kbd>Del</kbd> to delete the just the row contents.

Comment: alright, it works PARTIALLy! thank you, but after i press Backspace, it still prompts me to select what i want to delete - 4 option little window pops up, "delete column", "shift cell up", "shift row up" , i wanted one single shortcut that lets me delete entire row ALL AT ONCE, but still thank you!

Answer (score 4):

(I just tweaked what David suggested)

Select the cells in the row (or several rows) and drag the cursor to outside the table in such a way that the entire row (or rows) along with a small area outside the table boundary is highlighted. Then press backspace. The entire row (or rows) will be deleted in one go.

Comment: Thanks for this, it works perfectly - no popup dialog box.

Comment: The popup is not shown **ONLY IF** you select also the area outside table, in right, near the row(s) you need. It extends the table with about half centimeter.

Comment: Also the whole row must be selected.

Answer (score 3):

1. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd> to select rows.
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

Comment: Worked. Just like a GTA Vice city cheat code.

Answer (score 0):

Content-wise: Mark the rows you'd like to delete and hit <kbd>Del</kbd>.

If you want to delete the row itself which is apparently what you intend to, i.e. you want to reduce the number of rows:

- Click into the row(s) you'd like to delete. Or set the focus mark in the row with your keyboard's arrow keys.
- hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, hit <kbd>-</kbd> (minus sign), then let go of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
- hit <kbd>r</kbd> (for selecting **r** ows, you'll observe you can use <kbd>c</kbd> for **c** olumns)
- hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

To delete a row with one keystroke without having to select it first, add the command "Delete Rows" as the first item of the [quick access toolbar](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-the-quick-access-toolbar-43fff1c9-ebc4-4963-bdbd-c2b6b0739e52). Then you can hit Alt+1 to delete the row your cursor is currently in.